# Unexpected subversion conflict behavior (Conflict with no conflicts)

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, conflict

I've been getting frustrated with some subversion conflicts i've been getting for a long time now.

I'm talking about when I do an update on a file and it says there are conflicts, so I open the file and there's no <<<< >>>> stuff in there.  In tortoisesvn or visualsvn I go "Edit Conflicts" and there are no red conflict zones.  On the file system there are 2 additional files generated from the conflict...

I've been using subversion for several years and only in the past year on my work machine has this behavior been occurring.  Because of this I've stomped many of my team mates commits because of the conflicted state with that doesn't display conflicts.

I had a team mate commit append a few characters to a line and this happened again today.  There is no way this should be happening, is a configuration file on my machine messed up or is there a bug in subversion?  Anybody else have this happen?

Thanks

TO MAKE THINGS ABSOLUTELY CLEAR...

When there is a conflict... I want there to be "<<<<<<<<<<< >>>>>>>>>>> ===" stuff in my file.  And when I say edit conflict it should show me the conflicts. When for some stupid reason SVN can't merge the revisions, and flags the file as a conflict, SHOW ME THE CONFLICTS. It's no use to me if SVN just dumps 2 files to disk, one of my current revision and another of trunk.  If I have to compare files manually then what good is source control.  If it can't merge show me the conflicts.  Somethings gotta be screwy.

Comment: My teammate experiencing a problem like that. Sometimes he overrides our code and he says "i didn't see any conflict". How did you solve this problem? I checked svn:mime-type property and it is "text/plain"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your file treated as binary by Subversion?
(To check: Does it have a svn:mime-type property that doesn't start with text/?)

In that case no markings will be added, and all local changes will be seen as conflicts when a new update arrives. Diff editors that guess the filetype won't have an issue resolving these conflicts.